# Apache 2.4 - mod_ratelimit breaks mod_autoindex

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to use [mod_ratelimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html) to enable bandwidth limiting on my entire apache server.

If I add the following to my apache2.conf:

```
SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
SetEnv rate-limit 1024
SetEnv rate-initial-burst 1024
```

my indexes stop working. I'm using [fancy-index](https://github.com/Vestride/fancy-index), and have copied the contents of its [.htaccess](https://github.com/Vestride/fancy-index/blob/master/.htaccess) into my `mods-enabled/autoindex.conf`

The html that the server returns when I access an index is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancy-index/style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

If I instead add those rate limit lines to a `<Directory>` directive, then the indexing is fixed, and rate limiting works on that folder. However, I'm trying to use this to rate-limit [Nextcloud](https://github.com/nextcloud/server) downloads, and applying the limit to that virtual host or the root directory doesn't seem to work at all, hence my desire to apply the rate-limiting to the entire server.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known issue: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62568